# Storing data in Elasticsearch - OLTP

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a transactional application where the reps want to enter the tickets and I got to store them immediately. The reason I picked ES is because the techs may enter some unstructured data and they want to search on it later.

Is it ok to store the data directly in ES instead of RDBMS?
I think probably 5-10 users will be using this application concurrently.

I have already built using DJango/ES but just want to make sure I don't have any issues later.

Answer (score 4):

It is certainly 'ok' to store data in Elasticsearch instead of a traditional relational model, but that doesn't mean it's the right choice. Your use case sounds fairly simple, and more 'document' based that tabular. For this a NoSQL document store can be a good fit. Elasticsearch also offers shards as well that can replicate your data for both higher availability and resilience - for instance, if one of your concerns is backing up your data.

On the other hand, simply having some longer text fields is not a strong argument for choosing ES over a database system (RDBMS or otherwise) that you more familiar with or that has more built-in support for administrative functions.

If you have truly unstructured data - ie different tickets can have different fields - or you have a high volume of tickets, such that the full-text indexing and searching in ES provides a real performance gain, then it could be worth the learning curve.

The basic concepts page for ES is a good place to start. See the sections on Shards & Replicas.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_basic_concepts.html

This might also be useful: https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-uses-of-elasticsearch